# How to know which JavaScript function takes the longest execution time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm using jQuery to perform ajax callback and deal with lot of objects (over 150). Somewhere in my code there's function causing the FF browser to show this message:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
> You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.
> Script: mylocalserver/website/Scripts/jquery1.6.2.min.js:16

I need a way to know which script causes this to happen. If I can use firebug to do it, how could I use it?

Comment: What you mean by "deal" in *deal with lot of objects*? Please post some relevant code.

Comment: I meant by 'deal' that I'm creating over 150 jquery object and there's drag and drop, click, dblclick events and filtering events, of course not all of them happening at the same time.

Comment: You have probably a infinite loop. 150 object is not so much (if they are not so big).

Comment: Or maybe you have to much events listeners? Maybe you could delegate some of them? http://blog.frontendforce.com/2010/04/event-delegation-with-javascript/

Comment: Post your code and we might be able to help you optimize it. Please use `@` when replying to comments and let us know when you add the code.

Comment: Tank you all for your help.
@lord_t : post your first comment as an answer please.

Comment: @lord_t just another question, are 8600 objects too much ?

Comment: How many date you have in them? Only simple data or functions?

Comment: @lord_t just simple data and no functions no dates

Comment: I think if you have more than 500k then MAYBE will be some problem, I think it depends on machine you launching. Write some simple test:
`a = [];
for(var i = 0; i< 1000000; ++i) {
a.push({a:12,b:2,c:4555,d:444});

}` and see how many you can incresing limit of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably a infinite loop. 150 object is not so much (if they are not so big).

Comment: The problem solved by dispensing the SlideUp and SlideDown effects when dealing with so much elements ( 9K and more ).